# Can't find login items in users and groups

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

So I've read all the posts on here and looked in every recommended folder for my start up programs and can't find a single one, I'm definitely the administrator on my laptop so I don't know what to do besides go to Apple. I have a macbook pro mid 2010 with Yosemite. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Not all things that launch at startup or login live in the Login Items. What are you trying to do - look at existing startup items or add your own?

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences → Users & Groups → *your user account* → Login Items

You can't view the list of login items for other users, even if you are an administrator.

Comment: I'm the only user on my laptop though

Comment: @DevonC. What exactly do you see in Users & Groups? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I don't know how to add an image on here I don't see a button for it but it's just empty, it looks like yours but with no listed items